# how to customize colorkey legend in R

Tags: r

I was wondering if there was any way to have the colorkey other than the default rectangular. something like this perhaps:

[image]

or if not how can I add < or > at the ends of a legend? like this:

[image]

my  color key:

```
color_range <- colorRampPalette(c("aliceblue", "deepskyblue3","darkblue"))
    my_colors <- color_range(10)
    my.at=seq(0,20,by=2)
    my.brks=seq(0,20,by=2)
    myColorkey <- list(at=my.at, labels=list(at=my.at))
```

EDIT:
I'm assuming a random raster:

```
    set.seed(123)
r <- raster(nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r), min = 0, max = 20)
crs(r)<-NA


levelplot(r, col.regions=my_colors, at=my.at,margin=F, colorkey=myColorkey, par.settings=list(axis.line=list(col=NA)), 
          main="Random Raster")
```

EDIT: I got how to get the < and >: `myColorkey <- list(at=my.at, labels=c("< 0","2","4","6","8","10","12","14","16","18","> 20"))`

Comment: Could you please share your complete code to get the legend?

Comment: Hi @Quinten..Please have a look at the edit. I hope I made things clearer

Comment: I get the following error when running your code: `Error in UseMethod("levelplot") : 
  no applicable method for 'levelplot' applied to an object of class "c('RasterLayer', 'Raster', 'BasicRaster')"` From which package is `levelplot`?

Comment: @Quinten please try library("lattice")